# Java reading JSON with multiple objects

Tags: java, json

The json looks like:

```
{
  "id": "SMAAZGD20R",
  "data": [
    {
      "blukiiId": "CC78AB5E73C8",
      "macAddress": "CC78AB5E73C8",
      "type": "SENSOR_BEACON",
      "battery": 97,
      "advInterval": 1000,
      "firmware": "003.007",
      "rssi": [
        {
          "rssi": -96,
          "timestamp": 1594642177138
        }
      ],
      "beaconSensorData": {
        "environment": [
          {
            "airPressure": 994.4,
            "light": 5,
            "humidity": 26,
            "temperature": 28.4,
            "timestamp": 1594642177138
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The code looks like:

```
public class getJSON
{
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
       
       try{
           Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\test.json"));
           JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
           JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray)jsonObj.get("data");
           
           Iterator itr = jsonArr.iterator();
           
           while(itr.hasNext()){
               System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"macAddress":"CC78AB5E73C8","rssi":[{"rssi":-96,"timestamp":1594642177138}],"advInterval":1000,"blukiiId":"CC78AB5E73C8","type":"SENSOR_BEACON","battery":97,"firmware":"003.007","beaconSensorData":{"environment":[{"light":5,"airPressure":994.4,"temperature":28.4,"humidity":26,"timestamp":1594642177138}]}}
```

I get an Array with the object "data", but the array includes only one value with all objects from "data".
How can i address the array "environment" and get the values tempreature, light,...

Comment: Hi Moritz, I'm not sure I understood your problem. From your JSON the "temperature" is inside "environment" which is in "beaconSensorData" in "data". You need to traverse all these objects to get the "temperature" from the "data". If your problem is in the output, you can create a new JSON and print the "temperature" inside "data". Btw, don't do casts to JSONObject and JSONArray, use getJsonArray for the latter.

Comment: Which `JSONParser` are you using?

Comment: import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Comment: @Moritz does the `data` array always contain single value

Comment: @Moritz is it necessary for you to use `JSON Simple`? as it was last updated back in 2012.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri No i never worked with json in java before, so i used jsonSimple

Comment: @Moritz actually, you have only one key `data` which maps to the entire object. So, it's correct what you get as a result. Generally,  I recommend you to use either `Jackson` or `Json` Java.

Comment: what is your question is ?  you want to parse your original JSON or what?

Answer (score 1):

Have you should try to use a framework like [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson)
Who will let unmarshall your json to real java object of your choice
for example :

```
public class Data
{
   private String blukiiId;
   private String macAddress;
   private String type;
   ...
   private List<RSSI> rssi;
   private BeaconSensorData beaconSensorData;
}
```

With Rssi,BeaconSensorData another class like that etc...
Now your code will get Converted as below

```
public class getJSON
{
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       // Set any extra configs like ignore fields etc here

       try{
            Data data = mapper.convertValue(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json"), Data.class);

            //Now you can access the value as below
            data.getBeaconSensorData().getEnvironment().getTemperature();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is partially good. You could provide an example on how to use `ObjectMapper` to transform JSON into POJO. Another thing is, `RSSI` is should be a `List<RSSI>`

Comment: Exact, thanks for the RSSI. Another one have edit my answer thanks to him to

Comment: Environment is also a list of objects :) But I think it should nail OP's question

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser, please refer to the following java code by recursion.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class getJSON
{
    private static void visitElement(Object obj, Map<Object, Object> map) throws Exception {
        if(obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray)obj;
            Iterator<?> itr = jsonArr.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
                visitElement(itr.next(), map);
        }
        else if(obj instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
            Iterator<?> itr = jsonObj.keySet().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Object key = itr.next();
                Object value = jsonObj.get(key);
                map.put(key, value);
                visitElement(value, map);                 
            }
        }
    }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
       
       try{
           Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/test.json"));
           Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
           visitElement(obj, map);
           for(Object key : map.keySet())
               System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at my code below.

```
[

{
    "title": "Dywizjon 303",
    "year": 2019,
    "type": "Dokumentalny",
    "director": "Zbigniew Zbigniew",
    "actors": ["Maria Joao","Jose Raposo"]
    
},

{
    "title": "Szeregowiec Ryan",
    "year": 2006,
    "type": "Historyczny",
    "director": "Stanislaw Stanislaw",
    "actors": ["Rosa Canto","Amalia Reis","Maria Garcia"]
},

{
    "title": "Duzy",
    "year": 1988,
    "type": "Dramat",
    "director": "Penny Marshall",
    "actors": ["Rosa Canto"]
},

{
    "title": "Syberiada Polska",
    "year": 2013,
    "type": "Wojenny",
    "director": "Janusz Zaorski",
    "actors": ["Harvey Glazer"]
}

]
```

This is my Entity named Movie

```
package objectMapper.app;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="Class")
public class Movie {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="title")
    private String title;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="year")
    private int year;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="type")
    private String type;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="director")
    private String director;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="actors")
    private String[] actors;
    
    public Movie()
    {
        
    }

    

    public Movie(String title, int year, String type, String director, String[] actors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.type = type;
        this.director = director;
        this.actors = actors;
    }



    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    

    public String[] getActors() {
        return actors;
    }



    public void setActors(String[] actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [title=" + title + ", year=" + year + ", type=" + type + ", director=" + director + ", actors="
                + Arrays.toString(actors) + "]";
    }



    
    
    

}
```

Function to read movies.json

```
public Movie[] readJSONFile() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
        Movie[] jsonObj=mapper.readValue(new File("movies.json"),Movie[].class);
        return jsonObj;
    }
```

Lets do something with our POJO class

```
List<String> titles=new ArrayList(); 
        for(Movie itr: tempMovies)
        {
            titles.add(itr.getTitle().toLowerCase());
        }
        if(titles.contains(tempTitle.toLowerCase()))
        {
        for(Movie itr2 : tempMovies)
        {
            
            if(tempTitle.toLowerCase().equals(itr2.getTitle().toLowerCase()))
            {
                System.out.println("Title: "+itr2.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Year: "+itr2.getYear());
                System.out.println("Type: "+itr2.getType());
                System.out.println("Director: "+itr2.getDirector());
                String[] tempActorsStrings=itr2.getActors();
                int size=tempActorsStrings.length;
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Actor: "+tempActorsStrings[i]);
                }
                status=false;
            }
            
        }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Movie title does not exist!");
        }
```